Handling Dynamic Routes in Flutter with Azure AD Authentication
(Using aad_oauth, flutter_bloc and go_router from pub.dev)
When accessing the root directory of the web application, such as https://example.com, everything works as expected. However, when you attempt to access a subroute directly, like https://example.com/some/dynamic/route, Azure AD interrupts the flow. It fails because Azure does not recognize the URL in the redirect URI, which has not been added to the Azure configuration. This is particularly problematic as these URLs are generated dynamically and cannot be hardcoded into Azure AD's config. I am using BLoC State-management.
Let's break down the application structure and where the problem occurs:
Directly after my main.dart runApp(); I have this Widget:
class PlatformWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  PlatformWidget({super.key});

  final AuthRepository authRepository = AuthRepository();
  final ReportedBugsRepository reportedBugsRepository = ReportedBugsRepository();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("This gets Called at first");
    return  MultiBlocProvider(
          providers: [
            BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => AuthBloc(authRepository: authRepository)..add(AuthInitializationEvent()),
            ),
    //.... More Providers
],
          child: const AppView(),
        ));
  }

}
Then I come to my AppView where I made a switch while the authentication:
class _AppViewState extends State<AppView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(builder: (context, state) {
      switch (state.status) {
        case AuthStatus.inProgress:
    //... If AuthStatus.success the GoRouter and RootWidget is getting Loaded

But, the GoRouter and rootwidget don't even get loaded because azure interrupts me earlier in the tree, during the auth, inside my Business logic:
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  AuthBloc({required AuthRepository authRepository})
      : _authRepository = authRepository,
        super(const AuthState.inProgress()) {
    on<AuthInitializationEvent>(_onAuthInitialization);
    on<AuthLogoutEvent>(_logOut);
  }

  final AuthRepository _authRepository;

  Future<void> _onAuthInitialization(AuthInitializationEvent event, Emitter<AuthState> emit) async {
    print("This gets called");
    emit(const AuthState.inProgress());
    try {
      final token = await _authRepository.getToken();
      final email = await _authRepository.authenticate(token);
      emit(AuthState.authenticated(email));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(AuthState.failure(e.toString()));
    }
  }

}

And then we come to the Repos where Azure interrupts me and throws the error page with unknown route:
class AuthRepository {
  late AadOAuth oauth;

  AuthRepository() {
    final config = Config(
      tenant: "...",
      clientId: "...",
      scope: "User.Read",
      navigatorKey: globalNavigatorKey,
      webUseRedirect: true,
      loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
    oauth = AadOAuth(config);
  }

  Future<String> getToken() async {
    String accessToken = "";
    try {
      final result = await oauth.login();
      result.fold(
        (failure) => throw Exception(failure.toString()),
        (token) => accessToken = token.accessToken!,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
      rethrow;
    }
    return accessToken;
  }
    
  Future<String> authenticate(String token) async {  
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('${BUSINESSLOGIC_URL}/auth/getauth'),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: json.encode(token),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.body;
    } else {
      throw AuthException(response.body, response.statusCode);
    }
  }
}

The overarching question is: how can I set up the following authentication flow? "If I access the main route, authenticate normally. However, if it is a subroute, first redirect me to the main route, authenticate me there, and then send me back to the subroute."

!!!!!!READ THE DOCS!!!!!!!!!! :-D
There is a solution for this problem inside the aad package:
final config = Config(
      tenant: "-",
      clientId: "-",
      scope: "User.Read",
      navigatorKey: globalNavigatorKey,
      redirectUri: "${WEBSITE_URL}", //<--- You can place root URL or auth url here
      webUseRedirect: true,
      loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );

now i get redirected correctly.
